# why can't I compare web socket message data with string literals?

Tags: javascript, websocket, string-literals, arraybuffer

I've opened a web socket with a device but have to resort to non-obvious means to parse the messages that come back.

Why?

Say my web socket is called 'ws' and one of the messages I'm expecting has a data value of 'wibble'. I get different behaviour from these handlers that look functionally identical.

This version works as expected.

```
ws.onmessage = function (msg) {
    var cmd = msg.data;
    if (cmd.indexOf('wibble') === 0) {
        console.log ('ws: wibble');
    } else {
        console.log ('ws unknown: ' + cmd);
    }
}
// logs ws: wibble
```

this one doesn't:

```
ws.onmessage = function (msg) {
    var cmd = msg.data;
    if (cmd == 'wibble') { // cmd === 'wibble' behaves same
        console.log ('ws: wibble');
    } else {
        console.log ('ws unknown: ' + cmd);
    }
}
// logs ws unknown: wibble
```

I suspect I need to convert msg.data to a string via an ArrayBuffer but Safari 9.1 doesn't support ArrayBuffer.from () and I can't figure out anything cleaner than the IndexOf approach that works well enough.

Thanks!

Comment: That is probably because your message isn't simply 'wibble'. Check it using `console.log(cmd.length);` and let us know. A `\r` is enough to make it different.

Comment: What is `cmd.length`? Probably there are some characters after the `wibble` string.

Comment: you're right. cmd.length is 1 more than expected. The debugger shows cmd as a string with the value "wibble".